# Line integrals of a vector field

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

[image]

I had no problem with part (a) or (d). The sketch was fine, and if we were given the F in part (d), we can use Stokes' Theorem. However, I am struggling with (b) and (c). For (b) I know I must parameterise the path and split $C$ into $C_1, C_2$ and $C_3$ but I'm unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part (b):** The intersections of the given plane with each of the coordinate planes are $x+z=1$, $x+y=1$ and $y+z=1$, respectively. Now parameterize the lines consistently, which means that where one line ends the next begins.

**Part (c):** The surface is a portion of a plane. What can you say about the normal vector to the surface? Once this has been answered you compute $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}$ and the surface integral.

**Hint:** You can always parameterize lines as $${\mathbf r}(t) = \text{initial point} + t (\text{final point} - \text{initial point}).$$ As an example, for the line $x+z=1$ you can take the initial point as $(0,0,1)$ and final point as $(1,0,0)$. Therefore $${\mathbf r}(t) = (0,0,1) + t( (1,0,0) - (0,0,1)) = (t,0,1-t).$$

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you give me a little more information about parameterizing the lines?

Comment: @user43290 I've added one more hint.

Comment: I got $0$ for part (b), does this make sense?

Comment: Compute $\nabla \times {\mathbf F}$ and find out. :)

Comment: $∇×F = (0, x^2,y^2)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18350/discussion-between-user43290-and-mark-fantini).